# How to cache downloaded dependencies for a Jenkins Docker SSH Slave (Gradle)

Tags: jenkins, gradle, docker

We have Jenkins Docker Slave template that successfully builds a piece of software for example a Gradle project. This is based on the https://hub.docker.com/r/evarga/jenkins-slave/).

When we fire up the docker slave the dependencies are downloaded everytime we do a build. We would like to speed up the build so dependencies that are downloaded can be reused by the same build or even by other builds.

Is there a way to specify an external folder so that cache is used? Or another solution that reuses the same cache?

Comment: Probably you need to mount a volume that will point to the location where dependencies are downloaded and cached. Typically it's `$HOME/.gradle`, so I guess `/root/.gradle` in that case.

Comment: My build slaves are not Dockerized, but I use the [CloudBees Docker Custom Build Environment plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/CloudBees+Docker+Custom+Build+Environment+Plugin), which overall is similar I think. A little like what @Opal suggests, you can set a custom cache location by mounting a volume from your host to the container (in my case, it is done by the plugin) and setting the `GRADLE_USER_HOME` environment variable within the build on that volume.

Answer (score 1):

I think, the described answers work only for exclusive caches for every build-job. If I have different jenkins-jobs running on docker-slaves, I will get some trouble with this scenario. If the jobs run on the same time and write to the same mounted cache in the host-filesystem, it can become corrupted. Or you must mount a folder with the job-name as part of the filesystem-path (one jenkins-job run only once at a time).

Comment: It's true, at least for gradle, and I think there shouldn't be more than 1 build per machine at the same time. We usually run 1 build per machine simultaneously and most of the time the additional layer "docker" is unnecessary. JDKs, Maven and Gradle are already installed on the machines. But in some cases the developers need more tools, e.g. headless-chrome. Then the developer's are free to create custom docker images (on our nexus) and use them to build/test their application on jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

[Here's](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/#caching-data-for-containers) an example for maven dependencies, it's exactly what Opal suggested. You create a Volume, wich refers to cache folder of the host.

Comment: We have some docker-images for typical jenkins-builds equipped with Java, Maven, git-client, ...
On this clients we run different pipelines, wich need sometimes the same maven dependencies. Every pipeline creates on run its own docker-container (based on the image) and re-download the dependencies on maven-build again and again. We could mount a docker-volume specific for a pipeline to the container, but so every pipeline has its own maven-cache. Is this useful?

Comment: The shared example is for maven dependenies and not for gradle. It's not the some thing.

Comment: Provide the gradle wrapper from your VCS. In that example: swap .m2 folder with .gradle folder...  and in the Build step write "sh './gradlew build'"